# sql import from csv

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

i want import data like this **E:\hai\tmp\r** in the name_dir column
but went i import it its become like this **e:haitmpr**

how can i import it to db without losing **backslash**

please help me
im using sqlyog and import using csv file

Comment: replace \ with \\ in your csv file then upload and see..

Comment: E:\\hai\\tmp\\r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `\` with `\\` in your csv file then upload and see.

like- `E:\\hai\\tmp\\r`